# azure remote desktop cannot see worker role

Tags: azure, azure-storage, remote-debugging, remote-desktop

Recently i began to working with windows azure.
My problem is that i published worker role to my account on windows azure (free trial account).
I do it in visual studio. and Worker role is running- i know it because i can connect to it.
But when i log into remote desktop of my windows azure account i cannot see this worker role in task manager.
It is necessary for me because next step is to remote debug this worker role. Because in debug->attach to process in vs i see every process except this worker role which i would like to debug

Answer (score 0):

What process name are you looking for?  The process the worker role runs under is WAWorkerHost.exe not the name that you've given your role.